# index.html:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using a node.js server to serve an `index.html` file that imports a module which contains something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="SomeModule.js"></script>
.
.
.
<input id="plot_graph" type="button" onclick="plotGraph()" class="ghost-button" value="Plot Graph">
```

When I access the webpage and click the button I end up getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. I did some reading and realized I need to include the script as a `module` so I modified the `<script>` element to this:

```
<script type="module" src="SomeModule.js"></script>
```

The error goes away when I go to the page but as soon as I click the button I get the error `ReferenceError: module is not defined at...`

Can someone explain why my module can't be imported? How can I import this module?

```
SomeModule.js

import * as Chart from './node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js'
function plotGraph()
{
    .
    .
    .
}
module.exports.plotGraph = plotGraph; // Error complains about this line.
```

Answer (score 0):

module.exports is a CommonJS module, you should be using ES6 format.

```
...
export plotGraph;
```

and then use the function from a script

```
<script type="module">
  import { plotGraph } from 'SomeModule';

  document.getElementById('plot_graph').addEventListener('click', plotGraph);
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Node JS has some support for ECMAScript Modules such as import. However require works better . I think I use it in one of my projects No problems with require...

```
var Chart = require('chart.js');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
```

Just NPM install the module into your working directory and it works perfectly .